# Java problem in my array, storage numbers and check if there are true or false

Tags: java, arrays, verification

I have a problem in my array.
The idea is simple, I storage fill numbers in my array and I need to search those numbers, can be one number or more, I want to have the answer if the number I storaged exist and tell me True or False if don't exist.
When the method check True it work, but when check false it doens't work like true, why?
Here is the Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers;
    Scanner scanTotalOfNumbers = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers going to storage?");
    numbers= new int[scanTotalOfNumbers.nextInt()];
    Scanner scanNumber= new Scanner(System.in);
  for(int i=0;i< numbers.length;i++){
      System.out.println("Write the number.");
      numbers[i]= scanNumber.nextInt();
  }
  System.out.println("list of all the numbers");
  for(int a:numbers){
      System.out.println(a);
  }
  int[] search;
  Scanner scanNumbersToSearch = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner scanSearch = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("How many numbers you want to search?");
  search= new int[scanSearch.nextInt()];
  for(int i=0;i< search.length;i++){
      System.out.println("write the numbers");
      search[i]= scanNumbersToSearch.nextInt();
  }
  System.out.println("list of numbers to search");
  for(int i: search){
      System.out.println(i);
  }
  searchNumbers(numbers, search);

  }


static void searchNumbers(int[] numbersIn, int... searchIn) {
    for (int i: numbersIn) {
        for (int a : searchIn) {
            if (i == a) {
                System.out.println("true " + a);
            } else {
                System.out.println("false " + a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code have a lot print for me to visualize.
Why false acting like this?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?  You're printing out 'false' for every number that isn't the number you're looking for, which I think is not useful. But I don't understand what you want to happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code using Arrays :

```
static void searchNumbers(int[] numbersIn, int searchIn [] ) {
    for(int i=0;i<searchIn.length;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<numbersIn.length;j++) {
            if(searchIn[i]==numbersIn[j]) {
                System.out.println(searchIn[i]+"   Exist in your array");
                break ;
            }
            if(j==(numbersIn.length)-1) {
                System.out.println(searchIn[i]+"   Does not exist in your array" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can put the elements of the array to search for in an ArrayList and use .contains() method :

```
static void searchNumbers(int[] numbersIn, int searchIn [] ) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(searchIn.length);
    for (int i : searchIn)
    {
        intList.add(i);
    }
    for(int i : numbersIn) {
        if(intList.contains(i)) {
            System.out.println(i+"  Exist in your array");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(i+"  Does not exist in your array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an expensive way to do this, when the existing arrays will work perfectly well.

Comment: it is a simple code to learn array and ArrayList Methods , we dont talk here about complexity. and it is not more expensive than the original code !

Comment: Thanks!! I could neve image I could putted j ==(array.length)-1. Thank you for your help